# Gem installing error

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, tweetstream

Wont install this gem, and I get this response.

```
greg@greg-VirtualBox:~$ gem install tweetstream
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing tweetstream:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lssl... yes
checking for main() in -lcrypto... yes
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for openssl/err.h... yes
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... yes
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking for epoll_create() in sys/epoll.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling ssl.cpp
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [ssl.o] Error 127


Gem files will remain installed in /home/greg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-       p362/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/greg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/eventmachine-      1.0.3/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: you are missing `g++` as said in the error. search for how to install that and you should be fine.

Comment: sudo install g++, you are the man

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> make: g++: Command not found
>   Reading the output should is something that you should learn to do. Especially when things aren't going as planned.

Depending on your flavor of Linux. Use the package manager and install the gcc package.

**Arch Linux**: `pacman -Syu gcc`

**Ubuntu/Debian/Mint**: `apt-get install gcc` (you may also need to install `build-essential`)

**Fedora**: `yum install gcc gcc-c++` or `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"` (for all dev tools)

After installing the compiler rerun the gem installation and it should be fine unless you're missing other dependencies

Comment: Using Fedora 28, "Development Tools" didn't install gcc-c++.  I had to explicitly install that package.  This, however, did the trick for me.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 8):

You need to install gcc. 
Run this line:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

It worked for me (with ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Just saw the build was failing on tweetstream's github.

```
sudo install g++
```

fixed

Answer (score 1):

For Amazon Linux: `sudo yum install gcc-c++`